# if else condition with multiple criteria in MIP

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, indicator-constraints

I have problem like below
Decision variable x1 >= 0
But it depends on selection variable s1 as binary variable

If s1 = 0 then x1= 0 and
if s1 = 1 then x1>0

how I can write this as constraint for mixed integer programming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\epsilon$ be a small constant positive tolerance, and let $M$ be a constant upper bound on $x_1$.  Now impose linear constraints $$\epsilon s_1 \le x_1 \le M s_1.$$